# Bootstrap não está sendo renderizado pela _Layout

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho essa pagina layout. Esse layout já veio, não fui eu quem fiz. Só não entendi porque ele foi criado se optei por um projeto MVC Empty(Vazio), mas isso não está me incomodando.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="PedidoApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
        <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

        @Styles.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
        @Styles.Render("~/bundles/Estilo")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angularjs")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app")

    </head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
                @Html.ActionLink("Pedido", "Pedido", "Pedido", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Logística e Transporte</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Na minha página, fiz um Fieldset como teste assim:

```
<form>
    <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
        <legend class="scheduler-border">Start Time</legend>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label input-label" for="startTime">Start :</label>
            <div class="controls bootstrap-timepicker">
                <input type="text" class="datetime" type="text" id="startTime" name="startTime" placeholder="Start Time" />
                <i class="icon-time"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

E meu arquivo `BundleConfig.cs`

```
public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                 "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                 "~/Style/jumbotron-narrow.css"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angularjs").Include(
            "~/Scripts/angular.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Estilo").Include(
            "~/Content/Estilo.css"));
        }
    }
```

Coloquei um `Jumbotron` e não funcionou. Esse arquivo `BundleConfig.cs` eu fiz na mão. Abaixo um screenshot da tela com o fieldset. Veja que o `fieldset` não fecha e aparecem duas linhas em paralelo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
```

**EDIT1**

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) angular.js:4957 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   Failed to instantiate module PedidoApp due to: Error:
>   [$injector:nomod] Module 'PedidoApp' is not available! You either
>   misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a
>   module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
>   argument.
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$injector/nomod?p0=PedidoApp
>       at http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:116:12
>       at http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:2297:17
>       at ensure (http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:2218:38)
>       at module (http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:2295:14)
>       at http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:4933:22
>       at forEach (http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:410:20)
>       at loadModules (http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:4917:5)
>       at createInjector (http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:4839:19)
>       at doBootstrap (http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:1949:20)
>       at bootstrap (http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:1970:12) http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=PedidoApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'PedidoApp'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.6%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DPedidoApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29348%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A116%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29348%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A2297%3A17%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ensure%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29348%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A2218%3A38)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20module%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29348%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A2295%3A14)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29348%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A4933%3A22%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29348%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A410%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29348%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A4917%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29348%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A4839%3A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20doBootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29348%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A1949%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20bootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29348%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A1970%3A12)
>       at http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:116:12
>       at http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:2297:17
>       at ensure (http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:2218:38)
>       at module (http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:2295:14)
>       at http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:4933:22
>       at forEach (http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:410:20)
>       at loadModules (http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:4917:5)
>       at createInjector (http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:4839:19)
>       at doBootstrap (http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:1949:20)
>       at bootstrap (http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:1970:12) http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=PedidoApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'PedidoApp'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.6%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DPedidoApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29348%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A116%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29348%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A2297%3A17%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ensure%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29348%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A2218%3A38)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20module%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29348%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A2295%3A14)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29348%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A4933%3A22%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29348%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A410%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29348%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A4917%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29348%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A4839%3A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20doBootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29348%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A1949%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20bootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A29348%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A1970%3A12)
>       at http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:116:12
>       at http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:4957:15
>       at forEach (http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:410:20)
>       at loadModules (http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:4917:5)
>       at createInjector (http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:4839:19)
>       at doBootstrap (http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:1949:20)
>       at bootstrap (http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:1970:12)
>       at angularInit (http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:1855:5)
>       at http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:33884:5
>       at HTMLDocument.trigger (http://localhost:29348/Scripts/angular.js:3468:5)

Comment: Beleza, pnet. Você adicionou a classe BundleConfig.cs ao Global.asax.cs?

Comment: Pq você não cria o projeto padrão do asp.net mvc já com os layout? Acho mais fácil você tirar o que não quer, do que configurar tudo no braço.

Comment: @CarlosScherer, sim, editei o post e coloquei lá o global.asax.cs

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas, dessa forma não vai haver aprendizado. Preciso fazer para entender a coisa. Tem que ser no braço mesmo, é mais didático. Isso é um teste para uma transportadora.

Comment: O console no navegador apresenta algum erro?

Comment: @CarlosScherer, erro apenas no Angular, mas eu ainda não fiz nada nele, apenas declarei. Editei o post e coloquei lá o erro no console.

Comment: Bom, seu Bundle está funcionando porque ele localizou o AngularJs. Remove a tag link onde está o Bootstrap que está duplicada e verifica se o cabeçalho fica igual, pois ele está aplicando o Bootstrap.

Comment: @CarlosScherer, apesar de eu ter postado sem o comentário, no códigio que eu estou usando, as tags link estão todas comentadas. Deixei apenas os Renderers ligados.

Comment: @pnet O arquivo ~/Style/jumbotron-narrow.css realmente está nesta pasta? Porque não há problema com o bootstrap já que ele está sendo aplicado ao seu cabeçalho, assim como o AngularJs. Assim não há problema com o Bundle.